# systemd Restart=always confusion

Tags: linux, shell-script, systemd, services

When we create and start a system service running, to run a script, if we include *Restart=always* in the .service file, does this mean that it again executes *ExecStart* after the script finishes and hence keeps executing the script in a loop?

I'm looking at a service file in a project, which is below, and trying to understand exactly what is happening here. Does app_script.sh start get called continuously, or only if the system service stops? I'm confused about this.

```
[Unit]
Description=application script 
ConditionPathExists=/application
After=network.target app.service data.service 

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/application/app_script.sh start
ExecStop=/application/app_script.sh stop
#RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Does `/application/app_script.sh start` exit after the app has started? Also, have you seen [`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=)? It says `Restart=always` will restart even if it was a clean exit.

Comment: @muru I saw it of course, however I still don't understand it. "will restart even if it was a clean exit" : If what exits? The script? the service itself?

Comment: Whatever is run by any `ExecStart`, `ExecStartPre` and all the others specified there. Hence the question: does this `app_script.sh` exit after the app has started?

Comment: In the case I enable RemainAfterExit=yes , what is the situation then, the service will remain active and won't restart?

Comment: `RemainAfterExit` has nothing do with this. As the docs say, this is about restarting when the process has exited. `RemainAfterExit` is only about whether the service is considered active or not.

Answer (score 3):

> If we include Restart=always in the .service file, does this mean that it again executes ExecStart after the script finishes and hence keeps executing the script in a loop?

The `Restart` option is only invoked if the started process exits; with `always`, according to [the systemd.service documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=), the service will be restarted if the process exits due to:

- Clean exit code or signal
- Unclean exit code
- Unclean signal
- Timeout
- Watchdog

The documentation goes on to say:

> As exceptions to the setting above, the service will not be restarted if the exit code or signal is specified in RestartPreventExitStatus= (see below) or the service is stopped with systemctl stop or an equivalent operation. Also, the services will always be restarted if the exit code or signal is specified in RestartForceExitStatus= (see below).

Since you are not configuring a RestartForceExitStatus nor a RestartPreventExitStatus, the process will only be stopped by systemd during a `systemctl stop` ("or equivalent operation").

> Does app_script.sh start get called continuously, or only if the system service stops?

Neither, as far as that goes. It does not get called continuously, as described above. Neither does it get called if the *service* stops (apart from calling `/application/app_script.sh stop`, of course); only when the *process* started by the service stops.

Do note that a `Type=simple` service instructs systemd to consider the `ExecStart` parameter to be the actual service. Your naming convention of `/application/app_script.sh start` implies that there's a shell script involved which probably invokes one or more other scripts or binaries. If your shell script forks off that process and itself exits, systemd will consider your service process to have exited.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm still a bit confused tho.After the script app_script.sh finishes executing, will the process exit?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question; you say the app_script.sh finishes executing, so ... of course that process exits.